# Paste text until 100% height

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make a script that will copy/paste this text, until 100% screen height has been reatched:

```
<p class="text">Jeg er 19 år og elsker sprut, penge og ligegyldig sex ahhh.</p>
```

But i am completely lost how i should do it, I know i can be done with jquery, but not sure how?

This is my css for the div around the text area the text should be placed in:

```
.CenterMarg {
    font-size: 35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "past this code"?

Comment: It should be dynamic pasted by jquery untill 100% screen height reatched. So it would look like this, but not as static: [link](http://prntscr.com/d3isbi)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wnat the content go go beyond the bottom (scroll) you will need to discount the text height or use `overflow: hidden` in your CSS.

```js
var b = $('.container'),
    t = $('.text');

while (b.height() < window.innerHeight) {
  t.clone().appendTo(b);
}
```

```css
.text {
    font-size: 35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">Jeg er 19 år og elsker sprut, penge og ligegyldig sex ahhh.</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice! It allmost works! It still does give me a scrollbar, and it's making 50% of the text smaller? [link](http://prntscr.com/d3j194)

Comment: Good, I can't tell you why the font size changed without you CSS files.